# How to get twitter timeline of specific area using twitter api?

Tags: twitter

I want to get twitter timeline in specific area like Korea or Japan. etc.

Is there twitter api for this work?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest solution to what you're looking for is using the place operator in the search API.

You will first need to lookup the location's place id, then provide it within the search query.

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/places/finding-tweets-about-places